# Which all kinect models with stereo cameras are compatible with ROS?

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We need to map a room with kinect and ROS. Which of the kinect model will be a better option? Is every model of kinect compatible with ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191019/which-all-kinect-models-with-stereo-cameras-are-compatible-with-ros-?/) by [robospace](https://answers.ros.org/users/18911/robospace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-08-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-22**:
this is only half a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The original Xbox Kinect works quite well with ROS, using the openni drivers.

The Kinect 2 is still experimental - some setups I've seen use a separate Windows PC to run the driver and forward data to ROS running on a Linux machine.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0